# Recommendations for acquiring (affordable) font bundles

Tags: fonts, typography, resource-recommendations

I have never - technically - bought a font for personal use (I can state that in shame, all the fonts I've bought were for clients or came with software I own). It's now time to spend some gold coins on nice typography, and I was wondering if there are **foundries that offer font packs or bundles.**

I imagine the bundle to be something like: *Popular font + Less popular but quite nice font + 3 or 4 little ones*. I would even prefer acquiring less known fonts, like these [beautiful Canadian ones](http://www.youworkforthem.com/). And while some classics are good, I'd bend more towards new fonts (designed in the last 3-5 years).

Any recommendations on what's the best way(s) to buy these font bundles?  My gold coins are quite limited, I must say. The use I want to give them is mostly personal projects (graphic experiments).

Comment: A bit dated, perhaps but: http://typophile.com/node/30047

Comment: @DA01 I checked some of those links (that's where I found the Canadian foundry), but most were broken or looked a bit... how to say it diplomatically... *aged*.

Comment: I think I last updated that page maybe 5 years ago so, definitely 'aged' :)

Comment: Design magazines sometimes have promo bundles as a free giveaway (e.g. one or two weights each of 4 or 5 of a foundry's fonts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already... sign up for the [MyFonts.com](http://myfonts.com) e-newsletter. While not always in a bundle, there are *quite often* **huge** discounts on the fonts showcased in their e-newsletter. I'm talking $200-$500 fonts for under $80. Massive deals. The showcased fonts are often new designs.

In fact, an excellent example if you like the font: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rene-bieder/campton/ (was $80 on sale, now $250)

Answer (score 2):

You can join [creativemarket.com](https://creativemarket.com/). They've always got new goodies to share, and the pricing will really stretch your gold coins.

I'm just like you as far as being a habitual "borrower" of fonts. At one point, I borrowed the entire Adobe library (2000+) from the newspaper :-\  Ironically, there were so many fonts, and so many looked similar to one another (think Helvetica and Arial for example), that combing the library became overwhelming, and I deleted the whole thing.

Since then, I've stuck to my favorite 5-12. I know how to group them (headings/body) and if a client, or I want something "modern", going to creativemarket, or MyFonts is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few websites which have sprung up recently offering font bundle packages. Some are offered free and some are more premium. I have found the ones which you have to buy of better quality and you can pick up some pretty good deals at the moment, best one I have found so far was here http://fontbundles.net

Answer (score -1):

My tip is to use the google fonts.

They can be downloaded, and some has a licence to use them for print design:
http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/google